# Precompactness vs. Separability

Tags: general-topology

*I was always wondering...*

Given a metric space.

To what extend do these notions differ:
$$\Omega\text{ precompact}\implies\Omega\text{ separable}$$
*(Precompactness meaning totally bounded.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is community wiki.*

For precompact spaces one has:
$$\#S_\varepsilon<\infty:\quad\bigcup_{s\in S_\varepsilon}B_\varepsilon(s)=\Omega$$
Collecting these give a countable dense set:
$$S:=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}S_{\frac{1}{n}}:\quad\overline{S}=\Omega\quad(\#S=\mathfrak{n})$$

Conversely the real line is separable but not bounded, thus not precompact.